# VT100 Terminal State Report

Tags: linux, terminal, console, vt100

My knowledge on terminal emulators is a little sketchy, and in an effort to learn more about them, I thought I could experiment with some of the escape sequences and see what I can do.  One of the things I thought of to try was (pseudo-code):

```
pushTerminalState()
writeSomeDataToTheScreen()
popTerminalStateToRestoreItToTheWayItWasBefore()
```

In researching how to do this, I came across two control functions

1. [DECTSR](http://vt100.net/docs/vt510-rm/DECTSR.html) - terminal state request
2. [DECRSTS](http://vt100.net/docs/vt510-rm/DECRSTS.html) - restore terminal state

However, I am unsure how to use them.  For the DECTSR function I am trying `process.stdout.write('\x1B1$u')`.  According to the note on the DECTSR page, this should give a "response", but I am unaware as to where I should "read" the response from?  I naively attempted to read from STDIN, but as expected I only received keys from my terminal.

Any tips on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If your output is buffered, you have to flush it (to get all of the request to the terminal).  Also, your *stdin* may not be reading from the actual device...

Comment: @OP These sequences have nothing to do with your question. Perhaps 'switch to the alternate screen' and 'switch back' would be closer.

Comment: they are supported only on VT320 and up (https://vt100.net/emu/ctrlseq_dec.html), it's unlikely that your emulator supports them.